# Modifying $_POST variable before submitting

Tags: php, html

I'm making a quiz generator, and I have an HTML form with radio buttons for multiple choice answers.  Right now, when I submit my form, the contents of the $_POST variable looks like this when I submit it:

```
Array ( [a1] => Bob [a2] => Bobby )
```

(Bob and Bobby are the radio button choices I picked)

I'm generating this form using a PHP function, which returns an array of answers in addition to echoing the HTML form.  Is there a way to modify the $_POST variable to have an 'answer' field (for checking my answers), like this:

```
 Array( [a1] => Bob [a2] => Bobby [answers] => Array( [0] => Bob [1] => Bilbo ))
```

The above was one way I thought of to check answer array with $_POST array.

Edit: More info on what I have so far:

- I have a PHP function getTest() that echoes the HTML form, and returns an array with the correct answers.
- getTest() generates each question randomly, and as such the correct answers are random.
- The main problem is that I have two separate PHP files, questions.php and verify.php.

  - questions.php echoes the form using getTest(), and has the array of answers.
  - verify.php only has the contents of $_POST, **BUT NOT** the array of correct answers.

Is there a better way to check the results of the form submission in general?  Thanks!

Comment: why not just return correct answer

Comment: Array( [0] => Bob [1] => Bilbo ) is the correct answer in this example.  $_POST=Array ( [a1] => Bob [a2] => Bobby ) is what I choose in the HTML form.

Comment: *How do you get from "Bobby" (the input) to "Bilbo" (the desired data)?*

Comment: Question 2: A. Bobby B. Bilbo.  I selected A. Bobby (the wrong answer).  The Array( [0] => Bob [1] => Bilbo ) is returned by my getTest() PHP function

Comment: Then, *map the data back on the **server-side*** (put this in a *new* array,  say `correctAnswers`). This should be available since the server generated the data to begin with. **Do not** trust the client (e.g. `$_POST`) for "the correct answer" (unless you are using encryption and are handling replay issues, which is outside the scope of a simple program).

Comment: I'm not really sure how to map data.  I have a file called question.php that calls getTest(). This function echoes the form and returns the correctAnswers array.  In this form, my action is verify.php. So whatever answer choices I select are in the $_POST variable in verify.php. The problem is that the correctAnswers variable is stuck in question.php. How can I access this array in verify.php?

Comment: @jh314 ***Recreate** the array of correct answers* on the other/verify page (load it the same way). Use an "include" to keep the code to "get the test" (e.g `getTest`) in a centralized location.

Comment: When I call getTest from verify.php, I get another randomly generated answer array.

Comment: the way i see i think you should change your architecture, you could (assuming that your source of questions is a list that has a unique identification before it gets randomized) change the name of your radio button name to represent the unique identifier in the list say your POST array becomes something like `Array ( [a123] => Bob, [a456] => Bobby )` where a123 and a456 are the ids 123 and 456 in the list, that way you could iterate them when you pass it to your verfier, does that seem understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do a quiz is to have an answers array and a user input array. Loop through one and compare to the other using the same increment.

You can take all of your post variables and create an array print_r($_POST); Then, loop through this.

```
$inputArray = //the post data into an array
$answerArray = array('a','b','a');
$numCorrect = 0;
for($a = 0; $a < count($inputArray); $a++)
{
if($inputArray[$a] == $answerArray[$a])
{
$numCorrect++;
}
}
```

Comment: I need to get a hold on both the $_POST and answer arrays.  When I submit the form, I only have the $_POST array in my new PHP program.  How do I get the answer array?

Comment: I'm a tad confused here. You're answer array is on the client side?

Comment: generate it the same way you did earlier?  You can't pass arrays through $_POST variables.

Comment: I have a PHP function called getTest() that echos the HTML form and returns the answer array.

Comment: lol I must be completely lost. If you know the answers on the server side, just create an answers array. Then, once they post the userAnswersArray, just grab all of the post data, loop through it and compare it to the real answersArray. Does that make sense?

Comment: So I have a file called question.php that calls getTest().  In this form, my action is verify.php.  So whatever answer choices I get are in the $_POST variable in verify.php.  The problem is that the answers array is returned by getTest() in question.php.  How can I access this array in verify.php?  I hope things are getting less confusing now :)

Comment: Alright so your verify.php for some reason doesn't have the actual answers as your question.php does. But, your verify.php is what you are posting the data too. This isn't a great practice. Here's your options. 1. Put the answers array in your verify.php 2. Use classes to call the answersArray object in the question.php from verify.php. 3. Be super lazy and pray your users don't know how to view source and post them into a input with a hidden attribute.

Comment: (If you *must* use hidden-fields, also use an HMAC-hash or encryption to prevent modification of the "correct answers" sent back from the client .. although only encryption will prevent the client from being able to cheat ..)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transmit the answers when submitting the form, you could use inputs of hidden type (like ) which are invisible on the page. However it only takes the user checking the source HTML of the page to see these answers, so it might not be good for your use. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is a have a look at sessions.

- That way on questions.php you can save the answers to a session variable,
- Then on verify.php you can read the answers from the session variable and compare them to answered supplied by the $_POST variable

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to, you could probably just use a hidden field in your form for submitting an answer array. However, anyone can change your source and modify what the correct answer is.

The best way is to just have an array in your processing script with the same keys (a1, a2), but with the correct answers.

Your processing script would look like this:

```
$answers = array('a1'=>'Robert', 'a2'=>'Hobo');

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   if (!array_key_exists($key, $answers))
   {
       continue;
   }

   if (trim($value) == $answers[$key])
   {
        // correct
   }
   else
   {
        // incorrect
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want $_POST to contain an array you can simply use the bracket array notation on the name field of your form.

For example:

```
<fieldset class="Question1"> 
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question1Answer1">Question1Answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question1Answer2">Question1Answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question1Answer3">Question1Answer3<br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="Question2"> 
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question2Answer1">Question2Answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question2Answer2">Question2Answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question2Answer3">Question2Answer3<br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="Question3"> 
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question3Answer1">Question1Answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question3Answer2">Question1Answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="Question3Answer3">Question1Answer3<br>
</fieldset>
```

(Note that the fieldset tag is optional, I just included it to group things together)

The output in post will be an array $_POST['answers'] that will have one element for each question.  So if you selected answer 1 for question 1, answer 2 for question 2, and answer 2 for question 3 you'd have:

```
$_POST['answers'] = [ 'Question1Answer1', 'Question2Answer2', 'Question3Answer2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but looks like you are asking for solution Y, whereas your problem is X **([XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341))**

> The XY problem is when you need to do X, and you think you can use Y
>   to do X, so you ask about how to do Y, when what you really should do
>   is state what your X problem is. There may be a Z solution that is
>   even better than Y, but nobody can suggest it if X is never mentioned.

Usually it is not recommended to modify $_POST array, and also not to transmit Answers with the questions to client-side. Instead, the approach should be that because `questions.php` dont need answers, but `verify.php` does, so only `verify.php` shoul have access to answers.

For example, answer-lists are never transported to examination halls along with the question papers on the occasion of exams.

I have taken the liberty to modify your code structure. If you still want to go with your own code, please post it, and then you can get the answers you want.

Try to use this:

**`question.php:`**

```
<form action="verify.php" method="POST">
<fieldset class="Question1"> Complete this: ___<b>bar</b>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="foo">Foo<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="too">Too<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="cho">Cho<br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="Question2"> Complete this: ___<b>overflow</b> 
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="stack">Stack<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="stock">Stock<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answers[]" value="stick">Stick<br>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**`answers.php:`**

```
//correct answers
$answers = array("foo", "stock");
```

**`verify.php:`**

```
include("answers.php");
$user_answers = $_POST["answers"];
$user_answers_count = count($user_answers);

$error = "";
for($i=0;$i<$user_answers_count;$i++)
    if($user_answers[$i] !== $answers[$i]) //verify
        $error[] = "Answer for Question ".($i+1)." is wrong!";

if(empty($error))
    //Notify that user has passed the Quiz
else
    //Notify that user has NOT passed the Quiz
    //print the $error array
```

**Couple of Notes:**

- I have used `answers.php` as a different file, but if there is no special requirement, consider merging `answers.php` & `verify.php` (put `answers.php` code on top of `verify.php`) Even better, you could also merge all these three files into one.
- I have assumed that $_POST is sanitized.
- Sequence of Questions & `answers` array is same. i.e. `answers[foo]` is correct answer for `$_POST["answers"][foo]`